# Disabling the 'Aero Blur' from the Windows 7 taskbar (using C++?)

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, user-interface, taskbar

I found a small program a while back that let me disable the Aero Blur while keeping the transparency that came with the theme. The program worked on literally everything, except for the taskbar which still appears to blur everything that happens to be underneath it.

This curious behavior led me to experimenting with the DWM api, in C++. Sadly, this didn't really help me at all, since no matter what functions I'd use - like `DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow()` -, none of them would actually affect the taskbar in a way that I wanted them to. I even tried turning the alpha levels of the taskbar's owner "window" down, but sadly that didn't work either - It made the taskbar *icons* transparent too which is a no-no for me, and it didn't actually remove the blur it just made the effect weaker.

As it seems that my skills are not enough to accomplish this task, I'm asking you - how can I remove the Aero blur from the Windows 7 taskbar? (Possibly using C++)

Comment: Even the Microsoft programmers working on Windows 8 didn't manage to do this.  While glass is gone everywhere else.  Good enough for me to guess that this just can't work.

Comment: While this seems like a good (well structured) question, does it have any real use beyond personal interest? If this is for a commercial app, the task bar is not yours to change. I'm voting to close as too localised (when the bounty is over)

Comment: Well, taking into account that I've searched for _a while_ already and I've never seen a way to accomplish this, I'd say that it'd be a huge addition for example to the Windows theming community, and to a lot of people who are interested in customizing their Windows.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but there's an interesting observation over on super user, as to [the aero theme not blurring when the magnifying glass is used](http://superuser.com/q/466048/214257).  You might be able to use that info as the basis for a bit of a hack...

Comment: That's a pretty interesting effect. I just tried using the Magnifier tool on my taskbar, and it seems that the blur does not disappear completely but it does seem to weaken the effect quite a bit. Sadly I don't think I'll be able to figure out a way to effectively use this knowledge to my advantage..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a small program that will remove the blur.

[Link to DeviantArt](http://dblake1.deviantart.com/art/Taskbar-Blur-Toggle-0-2-0-412358153)

Answer (score 0):

Remove Transparency that will do, else go to

Personalize by right clicking on desktop.

There go to theme, personalize the theme,

and find transparency/opacity. if you want with no blur and enabled transparency make it 100%

else disable transparency.

this you can do using c++ by doing twiks with Registry.

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\DWM]
"Composition"=dword:00000000
"CompositionPolicy"=dword:00000000
"ColorizationColor"=dword:6b74b8fc
"ColorizationColorBalance"=dword:00000008
"ColorizationAfterglow"=dword:6b74b8fc
"ColorizationAfterglowBalance"=dword:0000002b
"ColorizationBlurBalance"=dword:00000031
"ColorizationGlassReflectionIntensity"=dword:00000032
"ColorizationOpaqueBlend"=dword:00000000
"EnableAeroPeek"=dword:00000001
"AlwaysHibernateThumbnails"=dword:00000000
```

this are the values for Windows 7,

if you will change here, you will get the result. it contains all things you need to change.

you may change values for this three
ColorizationBlurBalance, ColorizationGlassReflectionIntensity, ColorizationOpaqueBlend

I think that will do :)

Comment: I'm not looking to disable transparency, since the effect that I want to accomplish is a transparent taskbar without _blur_, and those registry keys you gave me, don't actually remove the blur, they just make it a bit less noticeable with the use of certain colors.

Comment: ColorizationOpaqueBlend is the main conflict, make it zero and you will see the difference, some are percentages for your information

Comment: I already had `ColorizationOpaqueBlend` at 0, and it's not even nearly sharp. I don't think you can accomplish this via registry editing.

Comment: I will get back to you after I will try something else, running busy